# Calculated Measure giving incorrect results in Power BI

Tags: function, powerbi, dax

I've got a table with a few columns. I'm trying to create a measure based on the values in two of those columns, Orig and Amount. Orig represents the percent of the amount that I want to calculate in my measure.

```
OrigMeas = SUMX('MyTable', ('MyTable'[ORIG]) * 'MyTable'[AMOUNT])
```

But as you can see below, the measure, OrigMeas, is not producing correct values. For example, 0.125 (orig) * 32400 (amount) should be 4050.

[image: Table]

Comment: In a blank PBIX if you hit "Enter Data" and enter the data you've displayed and add the measure you specified, this doesn't repro.

Comment: does your table contains implicit measures?